# Button linked to sounds onStart

Tags: android, button, audio, oncreate, drawer

I'm working on an app there are no errors with this app however whenever i test it on my phone there are supposed to be sounds when I touch the button however no sounds.

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {


/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment objFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            objFragment = new menu1_Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new menu2_Fragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new menu3_Fragment();
            break;


    }
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}


protected void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final MediaPlayer intromp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.intro);

        Button intro = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.intro);
        intro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (intromp.isPlaying()) {
                    intromp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    intromp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer holyshitmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.holyshit);

        final Button holyshit = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.holyshit);
        holyshit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holyshitmp.isPlaying()) {
                    holyshitmp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    holyshitmp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer limberthanwatermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.limberthanwater);

        Button limberthanwater = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.limberthanwater);
        limberthanwater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (limberthanwatermp.isPlaying()) {
                    limberthanwatermp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    limberthanwatermp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer sandpapernipplwsmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sandpapernipples);

        Button sandpapernipples = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sandpapernipples);
        sandpapernipples.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sandpapernipplwsmp.isPlaying()) {
                    sandpapernipplwsmp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    sandpapernipplwsmp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer raisemyweinermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raisingmyweiner);

        Button raisemyweiner = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.raisemyweiner);
        raisemyweiner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (raisemyweinermp.isPlaying()) {
                    raisemyweinermp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    raisemyweinermp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer alientacklesatreemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alientacklesatree);

        final Button alientacklesatree = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.alientacklesatree);
        alientacklesatree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (alientacklesatreemp.isPlaying()) {
                    alientacklesatreemp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    alientacklesatreemp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer nipplerubbermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nipplerubber);

        Button nipplerubber = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.nipplerubber);
        nipplerubber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (nipplerubbermp.isPlaying()) {
                    nipplerubbermp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    nipplerubbermp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer shittalkmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shittalk);

        Button shittalk = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.shittalk);
        shittalk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (shittalkmp.isPlaying()) {
                    shittalkmp.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                    shittalkmp.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

ActivityMain

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
```

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id = "@+id/container">
<!--Note for Ryan, id Container is needed because it will not display the navigation menu aka the container-->
```

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/intro"
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Intro"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/holyshit"
            android:layout_width="193dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Holy shit"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/limberthanwater"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Limber Than Water"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sandpapernipples"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sandpaper Nipples"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/raisemyweiner"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Raise My Weiner"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alientacklesatree"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Alien tacking a tree"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nipplerubber"
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nipple Rubber"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shittalk"
            android:layout_width="193dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Shit Talk"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>





<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.user.myapplication.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

There is also a very basic Navigation drawer. It has nothing on it only text so I am not posting that here because it's pointless
Everything works fine however the only issue is the buttons. I am really new to android. I initially had an onCreate instead of the onStart where the buttons' actions were because it had errors and I was told that It onCreate can only be called once per activity.

If you can give an answer and also provide explanation that would greatly be appreciated to improve my learning.

Answer (score 2):

remove the **onStart**

and transfer the value to **onCreate** 
it should be like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 final MediaPlayer intromp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.intro);

    Button intro = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.intro);
    intro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (intromp.isPlaying()) {
                intromp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                intromp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer holyshitmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.holyshit);

    final Button holyshit = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.holyshit);
    holyshit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holyshitmp.isPlaying()) {
                holyshitmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                holyshitmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer limberthanwatermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.limberthanwater);

    Button limberthanwater = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.limberthanwater);
    limberthanwater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (limberthanwatermp.isPlaying()) {
                limberthanwatermp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                limberthanwatermp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer sandpapernipplwsmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sandpapernipples);

    Button sandpapernipples = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sandpapernipples);
    sandpapernipples.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (sandpapernipplwsmp.isPlaying()) {
                sandpapernipplwsmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                sandpapernipplwsmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer raisemyweinermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raisingmyweiner);

    Button raisemyweiner = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.raisemyweiner);
    raisemyweiner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (raisemyweinermp.isPlaying()) {
                raisemyweinermp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                raisemyweinermp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer alientacklesatreemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alientacklesatree);

    final Button alientacklesatree = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.alientacklesatree);
    alientacklesatree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (alientacklesatreemp.isPlaying()) {
                alientacklesatreemp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                alientacklesatreemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer nipplerubbermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nipplerubber);

    Button nipplerubber = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.nipplerubber);
    nipplerubber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (nipplerubbermp.isPlaying()) {
                nipplerubbermp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                nipplerubbermp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer shittalkmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shittalk);

    Button shittalk = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.shittalk);
    shittalk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (shittalkmp.isPlaying()) {
                shittalkmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                shittalkmp.start();
            }
        }
    });


mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
mTitle = getTitle();

// Set up the drawer.
mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
        R.id.navigation_drawer,
        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
```

}

Comment: If anyone would like the project to look at let me know I will invite you to my repository.